# analytic solution poisson equation spherical coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spherical-coordinates, poissons-equation, greens-function

I'm trying to analitically solve a poisson equation $\nabla^{2}p(r,\theta,\phi)=f(r,\theta)$ in spherical coordinates; the boundary condition is $p(\infty,\theta,\phi)$=0.

I'm quite used to the software mathematica, however the built-in routines do not solve inhomogeneous equations.

Therefore i need other ways to get the solution; one of which might be the Green function:

$p(\boldsymbol{r})=\int_{\Omega}G(\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r'})\,f(\boldsymbol{r'}) \, d\boldsymbol{r'}$

however i don't know if the integrals involved in the above solution can be solved analytically.

Maybe the particular form of the rshd function $f(r,\theta)$ can be exploited to find a solution, specifically the function

$f(r,\theta) = \frac{A+B\,Cos(2\theta)+C \,Cos(4 \theta)}{r^{8}}+\frac{D \,Cos(\theta)+E \, Cos(3 \theta)}{r^{9}}+\frac{F+G \,Cos(2\theta)+H \,Cos(4 \theta)}{r^{10}}+\frac{I \,Cos(\theta)+L \, Cos(3 \theta)}{r^{11}}+\frac{M+N \,Cos(2\theta)+O \,Cos(4 \theta)}{r^{12}}$

Where A,B,..., O and so on are constants.

Any suggestion to solve this problem is very welcome!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the spherical harmonic expansion for $G$.  Then, compute the integrals in closed form.

Comment: I'm not familiar with spherical harmonics, could you please give me some reference/links where i can check some example?

Comment: One more issue ... the function $f$ is highly singular at the origin.  What is the domain over which you will be integrating?

Comment: I forgot to tell that the integration is done for $r>1$ so the singularity at the origin is not inside the integration domain

Comment: Great!  Then we can proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general way to proceed would be to expand the Green Function in spherical harmonics.  To that end, we have

$$G(\vec r|\vec r')=\frac{1}{4\pi|\vec r-\vec r'|}=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-l}^{l}\frac{1}{2l+1}\left(\frac{r_<^l}{r>^{l+1}}\right)Y^*_{lm}(\theta',\phi')Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)$$

where $r_<$ ($r_>$) is the smaller (larger) of $r$ and $r'$ and the spherical harmonic functions $Y_{lm}$ are given by

$$Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)=\sqrt{ \frac{(2l+1)}{4\pi} \frac{(l-m)!}{(l+m)!} }P_l^m(\cos \theta)e^{im\phi}$$

Here, $P_l^m$ are the associated Legendre Polynomials which satisfy the orthogonality relationship

$$\int_{-1}^1 P_l^m(x)P_{l'}^{m'}(x)dx= \frac{2}{2l+1}\frac{(l+|m|)!}{(l-|m|)!}\delta_{ll'}$$

Note that the proposed function $f$ is independent of the azimuthal angle $\phi$, which renders the integration over $\phi$ trivial.  It will reduce the problem to an integration over $r$ and $\theta$, which involves a single series over $l$ with only the Legendre polynomials $P_l^0(\cos \theta)=P_l(\cos \theta)$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Unfortunately i need further explanations; first i don't know what the symbols $r_<$ and $r_>$ mean, and how they behave under an integration over $r$. Second the solution here comes as an infinite series which i have to truncate at some order, am i correct? or are the terms above a certain order identically zero?

Comment: The terms $r_<$ and $r_>$ are explained in the answer.  If $r<r'$, then $r_<=r$ and $r>=r'$.  If $r>r'$, then $r_<=r'$ and $r_>=r$.  Now, while the Green Function has an infinite series, the form of $f$ will render the form for the potential merely a finite sum.

Comment: Ah true, i missed the explanation of the symbols! I still wonder if the integration over $r$ will yield an analytical expression... Thanks for the help it has been precious.  (in case i manage to get the analytical solution i will probably need help to solve a vectorial poisson equation...)

Comment: Well, you're certainly quite welcome.  It was my pleasure. For the radial integral, you will split in into $\int_1^rr'^2dr'+\int_r^{\infty}r'^2dr'$.  Also, the cosine dependence of $f$ can be written in terms of polynomials in cosine and you will be able to exploit orthogoanlity with the Legendre polynomials.  There will be a closed-form solution.

Comment: Ok i've reduced the $f$ function to a polynomial series in $Cos(\theta')$ and i carried out the integration along $\theta'$; i'm left with something like: $\int_{1}^{\infty} r'^{2} \sum_{l=0}^{4}K_{l}(r') (\frac{r_{<}^{l}}{r_{>}^{l+1}})P_{l}(Cos(\theta)) dr'$ where $K_{l}(r')$ are functions of $r'$; how should i carry out this integration? Any suggestion? (if you want me to post it as a question i'll proceed). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Split the integral into two.  The first has limits $1$ to $r$, the second $r$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick answer, i'm performing the integration along $r'$ i found something very strange that i try to explain: When i carry out the integration fixing $l=1$ , for example, the first integral (the one ranging from $1$ to $r$) yields a function that decreases as $\frac{1}{r^{2}}$ (you can verify this with whatever polynomial function $K_{1}(r')$ you want). Such decrease is indeed impossible because the laplacian of $\frac{1}{r^{2}}$ yields terms of order $\frac{1}{r^{4}}$; while the smallest order of $f(r,\theta)$ is  $\frac{1}{r^{8}}$. I hope i was clear...

Comment: Maybe this is caused because the domain i'm considering is the outside of a sphere of radius $1$ ($r>1$), but i'm using the free space Green function... I think this should be allowed as i don't have dirchelet or neumann boundary conditions on $r=1$ but perhaps it is not.

Comment: Are you sure? because the Laplacian of $r^{-1}$ computed  by mathematica is indeed zero In[42]:= Laplacian[1/r, {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"]
Out[42]= 0   While the Laplacian of $r^{-2}$ is not zero (again from mathematica):   In[43]:= Laplacian[1/r^2, {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"]
Out[43]= 2/r^4

Comment: I mistyped.  The Laplacian of $r^{-1}$ is zero.  The Laplacian of $r^{-2}$ is indeed of order $r^{-4}$.  Have you carried out the full integral yet?

Comment: Mmm not yet, i was scared by this so i stopped. Are you suggesting me that at the end they might cancel each other?

Comment: Well, the answer for $\phi$ has to be such that its Laplacian is $f$.

Comment: Well the problem is that each integration over $r'$, for each different $l$ index, produces a polynomial whose minimum order is $l+1$. Therefore i know in advance that they do not cancel each other... (this is due to the fact that the bottom boundary of the integral is $1$ rather than $0$)

Comment: When integrating between $1$ and $r$, remember that $r'<r$ so that $r_<=r'$ and $r_>=r$.  When integrating between $r$ and $\infty$, we have $r'>r$ and so $r_>=r'$ and $r_<=r$.  Does that help?

Comment: I didn't mess up with that, as i checked several times. Indeed Integrating from $1$ to $r$; $r_{<}^{l}=r'^{l}$ and $r_{>}^{l+1}=r^{l+1}$; the latter is the reason why the minimum order appear in the solution for each l is of order $r^{-(l+1)}$. In particular the reason is that by integrating between $1$ and $r$, as the lower integration point is substituted into the integral,  the dependence upon $r'$ vanishes and only $r^{-(l+1)}$ is left. This behavior would not exist if the lower integration bound would have been $0$. That's why i'm not sure whether the Green function can be applied here.

Comment: Did you remember that the differential is $r'^2dr'$?

Comment: Yes of course did. As i said before the problem occurs in the substitution of the bottom integration point $1$ into the integral, which leaves the whole polynomial dependency to be $r^{-(l+1)}$. You can verify this by choosing an arbitrary polynomial for $K_{l}(r')$ and carry out the integration between $1$ and $r$ yourself. For example you can choose  $K_{l}(r')=\frac{1}{r'^{8}}$

Comment: Did you constrain the coefficients so that $f=0$ at $r=1$?  That problem will go away.

Comment: Why should i constrain the coefficients? $f$ is indeed nonzero at $r=1$ as it should be.

Comment: Remember, it is the full Laplacian, not just the radial deruvatives that are involved.  As we know, the Laplacian of the potential will be equal to $f$.  So, the offending terms will cancel